# PHP Table Columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

So my PHP displays a MySQL table, I'm aware you can tyle these which I plan to. But as the image below shows, the add button adds another column. 
[image]

**Is it possible to make the add button below the two columns update and delete?** If so how can I do this. Here is my code, sorry for any errors or being messy, I'm still learning.

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
  echo "<form action=usermanagement.php method=post>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=id value=" . $record['ID'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=rank value=" . $record['Rank'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=username value=" . $record['Username'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=password value=" . $record['Password'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['ID'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete" . " </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>";
}
echo "<form action=usermanagement.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uid></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=urank></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uusername></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=upassword></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=add value=add" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: btw, you never closed off `<input type=submit name=add value=add` and you really should quote your input attributes as will many of your other inputs which will fail you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the closing tags of the inputs.. the hidden inputs can be put anywhere in the table as they not being displayed:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
    echo '<form action=usermanagement.php method=post>
              <tr>
                   <td>
                        <input type=text name=id value="' . $record['ID'] . '" />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                        <input type=text name=rank value="' . $record['Rank'] . '" />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                        <input type=text name=username value="' . $record['Username'] . '" />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                        <input type=text name=password value="' . $record['Password'] . '" />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                        <input type=hidden name=hidden value="' . $record['ID'] . '" />
                        <input type=submit name=update value=update />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                        <input type=submit name=delete value=delete />
                   </td>
              </tr>
          </form>';
}

echo '<form action=usermanagement.php method=post>
          <tr>
               <td>
                    <input type=text name=uid />
               </td>
               <td>
                    <input type=text name=urank />
               </td>
               <td>
                    <input type=text name=uusername />
               </td>
               <td>
                    <input type=text name=upassword />
               </td>
               <td colspan="2">
                    <input type=submit name=add value=add />
               </td>
          </tr>
      </form>';
```

Also, try stop using `mysql_*` functions as they being deprecated. Use `PDO`, `mysqli_` or the `MySQLi` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this:

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=add value=add" . " </td>";
```

By this:

```
echo "<td colspan='3'>" . "<input type=submit name=add value=add" . "></td>";
```

Comment: Partly, yes. However this will throw a parse error for a few reasons.

Comment: Also there is no need to wrap hidden field in `<td>`'s, so it will looks like:`echo "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['ID'];`

Comment: many of their other inputs are missing the closing `>`. so, you may have to rework their code. I've placed a comment under their question about it.

Comment: `<td colspan="3">` that will cause a parse error and should either be single quotes, or to escape them `<td colspan=\"3\">`. Because the echo is set in double quotes. **Edit:** `<input type=submit name=add value=add` should be `<input type=submit name=add value=add>` but they really should be quoting those too.

Answer (score 0):

Use css (add class="add" to the add button):

```
 .add{
   position: relative;
   left: 50px; (...adjust)
 }
```